# How do you form the 'north' and 'south' versions of 'occident' and 'orient'?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, vocabulary, analogy, word-formation

How does one correctly form the "north" and "south" forms for which *occident* and *orient* are "west" and "east"?

I found *boreal* and *austral*, but those look like adjectives and I'm after the nouns.

Bonus: what about "up" and "down"?

Comment: I like 'zenith' and 'nadir' for 'up' and 'down', but definitely 'boreal' and 'austral' for 'north' and 'south'. Bonus points all round. :)

Comment: Orient and occident come from Latin for "rising" and "setting". What is the equivalent thing in the north and south?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The words *orient* and *occident* are two of the set of [six French words](http://members.tripod.com/~gremio_fenix/trabalhos/orient_occident.html)

> orient, occident, zénith, nadir, septentrion, midi,

which form the set you were looking for. The word [*septentrion*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/septentrion) (north) is obsolete in English, and I can find no evidence that *midi* (formerly spelled *midy*) was ever an English word at all.

In Old French, the word *méridien* was used instead of *midi* (see [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud)), so another possible sixth term is *meridian,* which is indeed an English word which has occasionally been used to mean the opposite of *septentrion*; see for example this reference from [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=KNgRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA300&dq=septentrion+meridian&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bAq1T9OLLYf88gTp1_HUDw&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=septentrion%20meridian&f=false). So maybe the best answer is:

> orient, occident, zenith, nadir, septentrion, meridian.

You shouldn't expect anybody to understand the meaning of the last two terms without explanation, though.

Comment: Midi is in Chambers, defined as "The south (of France)."

Comment: @Shyam: that is also the current meaning in French.

Comment: +1 about the explanation for the last two.  Meridian always makes me think of the dividing line or middle.

Comment: Zenith and nadir are English, but the other two are not recognizable for what they are intended.

Comment: Indeed, if you want to be understood you should use *orient, occident, zenith, nadir, north, south.*

Comment: I considered putting 'equatorial' in my list of words, as an absolute middle between 'boreal' and 'austral', but I can see how 'equatorial' and 'meridian' might mean 'southerly' to a boreocentric culture.

Comment: @PeterShor, when I wish to be understood, I say *east*, *west*, *up*, *down*, *north*, *south*... (In all seriousness though, this was a very good answer, +1)

Comment: @android weasel: 'septentrion' is also boreocentric, since it refers to the seven stars in *Usra Minor* (or maybe *Ursa Major*).

Comment: @PeterShor: It rather makes sense for a word meaning "of the north" to be boreocentric. ;-)

Comment: Why wouldn't anybody be able to understand meridian without explanation? The "Prime Meridian" is a common term used on maps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian

Answer (score 11):

I think *boreal* and *austral* may be the closest you'll get.

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=auster&allowed_in_frame=0), The noun form of *austral* is an English word:

> **auster** 
>   "south wind," late 14c., from L. *auster* "the south wind; the south country" (see Australia).

However, the noun form of *boreal*, is only the Latin for north wind, *boreas*, or the name of the Greek god of the north wind, *Boreas*.

Comment: Boreal and austral are certainly what I’ve always used.  Boreal forests and all.  Plus the two *aurorae*.

Comment: @tchrist Haha - I'm struck by the idea of an a-boreal forest: a forest with no trees? Oh.. damn: ar-boreal. Doesn't work. :o)

Comment: @Callithumpian - I think that's the closest to Orient and Occident - I can imagine trains called 'The Auster Express' or 'The Boreas Express'. Perhaps I'll put them into the novel I'm writing in my copious free time.

Answer (score 7):

In Portuguese the words are "meridional" and "setentrional", both with roots on French. I checked on-line and saw that "Meridional" and "Septentrional" are valid English words.

Answer (score 2):

*North* and *south* can both be nouns, enabling us to speak of *the North* and *the South*, just as we speak of *the Orient* and, perhaps less often, *the Occident*. To be consistent, we'd then have to speak of *the East* and *the West*.

Comment: But it was precisely 'How would I style a word based on "Boreal" to refer to "The North", and "Austral" to refer to "The South", if I wanted it to be consistent with "The Orient" and "The Occident"' that I sought in asking my question. I already know about 'The East' and 'The West', but those are plain workaday words with no mystique and little poetry.

Answer (score 2):

The nouns from which *borealis* and *australis* derive are *boreas* (Greek *Βορέᾱς,* wind from the North) and *auster* (Lat. *auster,* wind from the South). You, probably, can use Boreas and Auster as artistic expressions to denote, metonymously, the North and the South, as in

*...The man that came from the lands of Boreas...* (meaning, probably, Russia or Canada)

This would sound rather quaint—but, for that matter, you do not come across *Orient* and *Occident* much in everyday speech, either.

It is interesting that, while the ancient people associated the East and the West with the dawns (Lat. *oriens, -tis* and *occidens, -tis* actually mean *sunrise* and *sunset*), the North and the South were associated with cold (Northern) and hot (Southern) wind. This is understandable: our ancient ancestors were dependent on the forces of the Nature ☁☀☁ much more, so natural phenomena like where the sun rises and sets, and which wind direction causes warmer or colder weather, were much more meaningful to them than to us city rats.

Comment: The ancient Romans also associated *North* with Ursa Minor; see [septentrio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/septentrio#Latin), and *South* with noon; see [meridies](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meridies#Latin).

Comment: Oh, yes, and this still goes on: even nowadays, if you want to find the North at night you look for the Polaris (the tail end of the Ursa Minor), and you know that at noon the shadow points to the South, along your meridian—not everywhere, though, because we now have time zones, and your zone time may differ by an hour from your astronomic time, which causes a 30° deviation (360°/12). This is all interesting, but it takes us still farther away from the original question than my last paragraph did, hehe.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the closest you might get to a modern correspondent to "austral" is "the Antipodes" (and adjective Antipodean).

Comment: Antipodes just means two opposite points, it says nothing about their **absolute** position.