# What is a "Tamazie party"?

Tags: meaning

I found the term "Tamazie party" in a play by [Joe Penhall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Penhall). Is it a party related to drugs? Or does it have an idiomatic meaning? If it is a special party, is it just in Britain?

Comment: Almost definitely related to Temazepam. Not idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to drugs, namely Temazepam, which is a hypnotic (ie a cure for insomnia). I have never heard the phrase 'Tamazie party' before, but I assume it refers to sitting around getting stoned on said drug.

Comment: amazing!  who knew?

Comment: Temazepam with an 'e'. (that's not a slightly different party)

Comment: Replacing a long word with a shorter version with "-ie" at the end is a common way of shortening words in Australian English. I didn't know our [podean](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78143/antonyms-for-antipode-antipodes-antipodean) friends did it.

Comment: Absolutely. Take a look at the nicknames in any cricket team on either side of the globe: Warnie, Freddie, Cookie etc :)